# Can someone explain how PostgreSQL decides which columns need to be in a group or aggregate function?

Tags: postgresql

I've seen several answers on SO about how to fix the error `column "whatever" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`, but I haven't really seen an explanation as to why, and which columns are chosen.

With MySQL I can add a single column in to my `GROUP BY` clause, and it works perfectly. With PostgreSQL, it basically wants me to add every column in to the group by (which is not what I want). This leads me to doing groups after the fact, and in most cases, this is a lot slower to process.

I have 2 tables here: `members` and `report_stats`. This first query works perfect.

```
SELECT 
  members.id, members.name, members.username, members.email, members.site_id, members.created_at 
FROM members 
GROUP BY members.created_at, members.id 
ORDER BY members.created_at 
LIMIT 1000;
```

This second query does not work. It wants me to add the `approved` column in to the group by. If I do, then it also wants the `view_stat_id`

```
SELECT 
  report_stats.installation, report_stats.approved, report_stats.view_stat_id, report_stats.date 
FROM report_stats 
GROUP BY report_stats.date, report_stats.installation 
ORDER BY report_stats.date 
LIMIT 1000;
```

Here are the structures of these two tables:

```
Table "public.members"
     Column         |            Type             |           Modifiers           
------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------
id                     | character varying(18)       | not null
site_id                | character varying           | 
email                  | character varying           | 
username               | character varying           | 
name                   | character varying           | 
created_at             | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
"members_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_members_on_created_at" btree (created_at)
"index_members_on_email" btree (email)
"index_members_on_site_id" btree (site_id)


             View "public.report_stats"
  Column      |            Type             | Modifiers 
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
view_stat_id     | character varying           |
installation     | smallint                    |
approved         | boolean                     |
date             | timestamp without time zone |
```

So my main question really is, why does the first one work and not the second? What makes my members table different that I can query 6 columns, and only include 2 of them in the the `GROUP BY`, but in the second one, trying to query 4 columns, I need all 4 in the GROUP BY?

EDIT: Running `PostgreSQL 9.5.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31), 64-bit`

Comment: Yup. I'm positive. I've ran it several times thinking I was going crazy. No aggregate function needed. I guess I should also put what version I'm using.

Comment: #1 works because you are grouping by the primary key!

Comment: The second table was actually generated by a UNION between 2 separate tables and used like a view. If I add a primary key to that, will that fix this?

Comment: You can't add constraints to a view :(.  It might work if you group by a view column that is a primary key in the original table...

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. I even tried the primary key for both. My guess is maybe because those fields are NULL on some records? No clue. Maybe I just need to go about doing this a completely different way, or just keep doing the grouping in the programming language after. Thanks!

Comment: You could put your view columns in group by clause, or wrap the select list items in aggregate functions.  It might be slow, but that might not matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Postgres will complain any time that you are trying to select a single value where there may be many in a group.  Example #1 works because you are grouping by the primary key, which means the other values will be unique.  Anything in the `GROUP BY` clause is also the same inside of each group, and can be selected.

The postgres manual for select says:

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it
>   is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped
>   columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column
>   is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would
>   otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped
>   column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a
>   subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the
>   ungrouped column.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY